# C++ shared pointer with derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, shared-ptr

I am trying to get shared pointers of a base class from a derived class. Here's the code:

```
class Base {
    public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Base> Ptr;
    Base();
    Base(const Base& orig);
    virtual Ptr getShared() = 0;
};


class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    // default constructor and copy constructor
    virtual Base::Ptr getShared() {
        return std::make_shared<Derived>(this);
    }
};
```

I am trying to use it to get a vector of Base::Ptr, like so:

```
std::vector<Base::Ptr> objects;
Derived d;
objects.push_back(d.getShared());
```

I'm running into problems with the copy constructor, and I know this has to do with breaking const-correctness by trying to cast a pointer to a ref behind the scenes. I just can't pinpoint what the cause is, or I'm making a wrong assumption. Any thoughts?

> Base.h:20:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Base*'
>   to 'const Base&' Base.h:19:5: note: candidate: Base::Base()

Edit:
Severin's answer led me to the right solution for this particular problem. Sahu's answer is correct, but I was trying to have multiple objects share a pointer for a single object. enable_shared_from_this is the way to go if you need multiple references to the same object without constructing additional instances. The catch is that calling make_shared on a pointer the first time does what you expect, but subsequent calls using the same pointer construct additional instances of that object using the pointer as an argument to the constructor. Correct usage of enable_shared_from_this will instead return a shared_ptr that shares access with all other shared_ptrs that reference the object.

Edit 2: For completeness, this situation was actually caused by misunderstanding the differences between passing by reference and passing by pointer. In this *particular* case, the real problem was a design decision elsewhere in the application. Food for though for others with similar problems.

Comment: looks like you want `*this` instead of `this`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `std::make_shared` (until C++17) is

```
template< class T, class... Args >
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

It will construct an object of type `T`, wrap a `shared_ptr` around it and return the `shared_ptr`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared for the details.

Use of

```
    return std::make_shared<Derived>(this);
```

is invalid since you cannot construct an object of type `Derived` from a `Derived*`. You need to change that line to:

```
    return std::make_shared<Derived>(*this);
```

It returns a `shared_ptr` that wraps a newly copy-constructed `Derived` object.

Comment: This is like advising someone learning to drive a car, to drive blindfolded in order to avoid seeing the scary traffic (or compilation diagnostics). What do you think the result of driving blindfolded will be? Check out [Severin Pappadou's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107009/c-shared-pointer-with-derived-class#comment83189755_48107009), it's more in a useful direction.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, better?

Comment: Yes, it's much more clear about what the OP's code would actually do if it were fixed. But `enable_shared_from_this` seems crucial to me for the (to me) apparent *intent* of the code. I think that's really what an answer should be about. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, can't do that. *It is permitted to call `shared_from_this` only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr`.*

Comment: Uhm, it's very late in the morning for me, but unless I think tired-like there are at least 2 ways to deal with that. (A) enforce dynamic allocation, e.g. by making destructor `protected` and using custom deleter, or (B) produce a `shared_ptr` with no-op deleter when the object isn't dynamically allocated. The last one is pretty ugly though. The point of `shared_ptr` is shared ownership with guaranteed lifetime, and that guarantee would be broken so one could risk accessing a no longer existing object via a dangling pointer. But I think (A) is good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
virtual Base::Ptr getShared() {
    return std::make_shared<Derived>(this);
}
```

`Base::Ptr` is of type `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.
`std::make_shared<Derived>(this)` will return an `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`

Even if `Derived` inherit from `Base`, `std::shared_ptr` is a templated class, and `shared_ptr<Derived>` does **not** inherit from `shared_ptr<Base>`

What you want is to return the correct shared pointer:

```
virtual Base::Ptr getShared() {
    return std::shared_ptr<Base>(this);
}
```